# Difference between jQuery’s .hide() and setting CSS to display: none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show-hide

Which am I better off doing? `.hide()` is quicker than writing out `.css("display", "none")`, but what’s the difference and what are both of them actually doing to the HTML element?

Answer (score 210, accepted):

From the jQuery page about [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/):

> "The matched elements will be hidden immediately, with no animation. This is roughly equivalent to calling .css('display', 'none'), except that the value of the display property is saved in jQuery's data cache so that display can later be restored to its initial value. If an element has a display value of inline, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed inline."

So if it's important that you're able to revert to the previous value of `display`, you'd better use `hide()` because that way the previous state is remembered. Apart from that there's no difference.

```js
$(function() {
    $('.hide').click(function(){
        $('.toggle').hide();
        setDisplayValue();
    });
    $('.show').click(function(){
        $('.toggle').show();
        setDisplayValue();
    });
});

function setDisplayValue() {
    var display = $('.toggle')[0].style.display;
    $('.displayvalue').text(display);
}
```

```css
div {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
    <button class="hide">Hide</button>
    <button class="show">Show</button>
</p>

<div class="toggle">Lorem Ipsum</div>

<p>
    The display value of the div is:
    <span class="displayvalue"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: The problem using .hide is after reload site the element hide still looking in 2 seconds

Answer (score 35):

[`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) stores the *previous* `display` property just before setting it to `none`, so if it wasn't the standard `display` property for the element you're a bit safer, [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) will use that stored property as what to go back to.  So...it does some extra work, but unless you're doing *tons* of elements, the speed difference should be negligible.

Answer (score 13):

Looking at the jQuery code, this is what happens:

```
hide: function( speed, easing, callback ) {
    if ( speed || speed === 0 ) {
        return this.animate( genFx("hide", 3), speed, easing, callback);

    } else {
        for ( var i = 0, j = this.length; i < j; i++ ) {
            var display = jQuery.css( this[i], "display" );

            if ( display !== "none" ) {
                jQuery.data( this[i], "olddisplay", display );
            }
        }

        // Set the display of the elements in a second loop
        // to avoid the constant reflow
        for ( i = 0; i < j; i++ ) {
            this[i].style.display = "none";
        }

        return this;
    }
},
```

Answer (score 12):

They are the same thing. `.hide()` calls a jQuery function and allows you to add a callback function to it. So, with `.hide()` you can add an animation for instance.

`.css("display","none")` changes the attribute of the element to `display:none`. It is the same as if you do the following in JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('elementId').style.display = 'none';
```

The `.hide()` function obviously takes more time to run as it checks for callback functions, speed, etc...

Answer (score 4):

To use **both** is a nice answer; it's not a question of either or.

The **advantage** of using both is that the **CSS will hide the element immediately** when the page loads. The jQuery .hide will flash the element for a quarter of a second then hide it.

In the case when we want to have the element not shown when the page loads we can use CSS and set display:none & use the jQuery .hide(). If we plan to toggle the element we can use jQuery toggle.

Answer (score 1):

Both do the same on all browsers, AFAIK. Checked on Chrome and Firefox, both append `display:none` to the `style` attribute of the element.

Answer (score -5):

See there is no difference if you use basic hide method.
But jquery provides various hide method which give effects to the element.
Refer below link for detailed explanation:
[Effects for Hide in Jquery](http://aspdotnetraining.blogspot.in/2013/11/jquery-hide.html)