# jquery refresh content in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have 2 divs in an HTML page -that need refreshing when an event is triggered. 
One of the divs, if `display:none` and will not refresh with the new data.

Is it not possible to refresh `display:none` divs? 
My JavaScript is below,

```
$('#messages_send').live('click', function() {
$.ajax({
    url: base_url + 'ajax/send_message',
    data: {
        username: $('#messages_username').val(),
        message: $('#messages_message').val(),
        saveid: $('#messages_savedid').val(),
    },
    success: function(data) {
        sending_message();

        var x = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

        if(x) {
            if(x.gp_id==80)
            {
                    $('#spn_ucredit').load(base_url + 'ajax/userdata/credits');
                    $('#overlay_credits').load(base_url + 'ajax/userdata/credits');
            }
        }
        //$('#spn_ucredit').html($('#ncd_id').val());
        //tmp_cost = $('#spn_ucredit').html()-$('#ncd_id').val();
        //$('#ncd_id').val($('#ncd_id').val()-tmp_cost);
        //alert(data);
        setTimeout(message_sent, 2000);
        setTimeout(remove_modal_box, 3000);
        setTimeout(message_revert, 3500);
        $("#saved_messages").load(base_url + 'messages #saved_messages > form');
        //setTimeout($("#messages_content").load(base_url + 'messages #messages_content > form'), 1000);
        //$.get(base_url + 'messages #saved_messages > form', null, function(result){ $("#saved_messages").html(result) });
        //$("#messages_content").css("visibility","hidden").show();
        //$.get(base_url + 'messages #messages_content > form', null, function(result){ $("#messages_content").html(result) });
        //$("#messages_content").css("visibility","visible").hide();
    }
});

return false;
```

});

Comment: How do you know the data is not refreshed ? Do you show the div at some point ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using .hide() lets a div be edited , while setting display:none makes it a lot harder

> "The matched elements will be hidden immediately, with no animation. This is roughly equivalent to calling .css('display', 'none'), except that the value of the display property is saved in jQuery's data cache so that display can later be restored to its initial value. If an element has a display value of inline, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed inline."

So if it's important that you're able to revert to the previous value of display, you'd better use hide() because that way the previous state is remembered. Apart from that there's no difference.

from resource on jQuery's `.hide()` [Here](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Also , there are SO questions on this as well - [Here's an example of one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396983/hide-or-display-none-jquery)

Comment: @ZathrusWriter - added sources